# Zebra printer not responding Python

Tags: python, zebra-printers

Hello I have installed Zebra package in PyCharm

I am trying to run following code to print config labels but nothing happens, not even an exception.
I can see that getqueues() is returning the right printer on location 0.

```
from zebra import Zebra
z = Zebra()
Q=z.getqueues()
z.setqueue(Q[0])
z.setup(direct_thermal=True, label_height=None, label_width=None)
z.autosense()
z.print_config_label()
```

Please can you help troubleshoot.

Thanks

Comment: Have you tried sending pure ZPL to the printer?

Comment: Sorry, I am a total newbie in this area, how do I do that?

Comment: [Here](https://www.zebra.com/content/dam/zebra/manuals/printers/common/programming/zpl-zbi2-pm-en.pdf) you can find the official ZPL doc. Use this as a starting point.

Comment: Thank you @DelphiCoder while the document is good, it doesnt really answer my question as to why my code isnt working? can you help me with a working example of a python code?

Comment: Sry, but I have no experience in Python yet. As a first step I would just make sure the printer is working correct.

Comment: What OS do you use and how did you install the printer (which driver did you select)?

Comment: @DelphiCoder finally got it to work using ZPL and the doc you referred to. My os was windows 10